# could not convert string to float: price[0] - python

Tags: python

I want to make a currency converter which will take the current exchange rate from yahoo and multiply it with the amount the user wants. But I cannot multiply them. Could you please help me?

I always get: 
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\Ioannis\Desktop\c.py", line 17, in realprice = float("price[0]")

```html
import urllib
import re

stocklist = ["eurusd"]

i=0
while i<len(stocklist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=eurusd=X"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l10_eurusd=x">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "the price of", stocklist[i],"is" ,price[0]
    i+=1

realprice = float("price[0]")

print ("Currency Exchange")
ex = raw_input("A-Euro to Dollars, B-Dollars to Euro")
if ex == "A":
    ptd = int(raw_input("How much would you like to convert: "))
    f = ptd*price[0]
    print("It is $",f)
if ex == "B":
    ptd = float(raw_input("How much would you like to convert"))
    f = ptd*0.7
    f2 = round(f,2)
    print ("It is $",f2)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: price[0]

[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsaXB.jpg)

Comment: If you're trying to access the first element of `price` then you would use `realprice = float(price[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
realprice = float("price[0]")
```

What you are trying to do is **convert a string with non-number characters to a float** which doesn't work.

More precisely you are converting the *word* `price[0]` to a number.

To fix this just remove the `"` characters in the line above. Like this:

```
realprice = float(price[0])
```

(expect edits since you have a few errors)